# Should the name of the Stack Exchange become "Computer Graphics & Programming"?

Tags: discussion

Should the name of the Stack Exchange become "Computer Graphics & Programming" or something more specific?

Each day I notice more and more people posting questions regarding graphic design or actual 3D modeling topics. I think specifying the name clearly might make it more clear that some people are on the wrong website. That could help save time for the mod's having to go and close the questions themselves if they don't get posted in the first place.

Comment: We [had a similar discussion](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/the-name-of-our-programming-and-research-site) early on, and the decision then was to keep the name the same. I'm interested to see if views have changed now that we've had longer experience of using the current name.

Comment: I agree that it could be desirable to change name to improve people's expectation of the site topic, but I don't think "computer graphics & programming" is quite the right answer. Let's think of something even more descriptive.

Comment: Computer Graphics: Research & Programming? The "research and programming" part would tell the generic graphic designer they're in the wrong place.

Comment: @ArjanSingh i dont think we have ever had a graphic designer  mistake the site. More general progammers who think computer graphics is the same as design of graphical elements. And 3D graphic software users.

Answer (score 3):

I see no bigger need to change... A small voice tells me that the name should be more specific but i don't think how we could be more specific without misrepresenting ourselves.

Mistaking the site mostly only really happens for 2 classes of people:

1. People doing general programming and are under the illusion that anything even remotely sounding like graphics is on topic.
2. People that are operating a 3D graphic application. Mainly because there is no place on the stack exchange network where they would be home. These people leak all over the place, mostly in *graphic design*, *stack overflow* and some of them find a home in *engineering* *.

Changing the name to "Computer Graphics & Programming" will not eliminate group one. And group two is just a aimless bunch which pop up everywhere because we pretty much kick them out of every stack without question.

* We could consider as a act of generosity include crowd two in our site. Not that i particularly want to answer a buch of 101 questions but, since they have no place to go.

Comment: Including those 3D app users would be an entire discussion on its own. One the one hand, it would make sense as it would cover the pipeline from authoring to rendering, but on the other hand it might drive away the current community, as it would probably get outnumbered by the 3D designers.

Comment: @JulienGuertault Yes, also 3D authoring user crowd is a bit dysfunctional since the beginners outnumber experts 200:1